# what's the difference between getDerivedStateFromError and componentDidCatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I understood from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/9lp0k3/new_lifecycle_method_getderivedstatefromerror/):

`componentDidCatch`:

- is called always in the browser
- is called during the "commit phase" when the DOM has already been updated
- should be used for something like error's reporting

`getDerivedStateFromError`:

- is also called during server-side-rendering
- is called in "render phase" when the DOM has not yet been updated
- should be used for rendering a fallback UI

Still, I'm bit confused about some things:

1. are they both catching the same type of errors? or each lifecycle
   will catch the different error?
2. should I always use both (in the same "error-catching" component possibly)?
3. *"using componentDidCatch for error recovery is not optimal because it forces the fallback UI to always render synchronously"* what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The statements in the question are mostly correct. Currently error boundaries aren't supported in SSR, `getDerivedStateFromError` and `componentDidCatch` don't affect server side.

> are they both catching the same type of errors? or each lifecycle will catch the different error?

They are catching same errors but at different phases. This previously was possible with `componentDidCatch` alone:

```
  static getDerivedStateFromError() {
    return { hasError: true };
  }
```

and

```
  componentDidCatch() {
    this.setState({ hasError: true });
  }
```

do the same thing, `componentDidCatch` has no chances to be supported on server side until the support for asynchronous rendering will be added to `ReactDOMServer`.

> should I always use both (in the same "error-catching" component possibly)?

You *can* use both. An example from [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidcatch) shows that:

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  state = { hasError: false };

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    logComponentStackToMyService(info.componentStack);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
    }

    return this.props.children; 
  }
}
```

In this case responsibilities are divided between them. `getDerivedStateFromError` does the only thing it is good for, i.e. updates the state if an error occurs, while `componentDidCatch` provides side effects and can access `this` component instance if needed.

> "using componentDidCatch for error recovery is not optimal because it forces the fallback UI to always render synchronously" what's wrong with that?

New React releases are aimed at asynchronous rendering which is more efficient. As it was also mentioned in [the comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/9lp0k3/new_lifecycle_method_getderivedstatefromerror/), synchronous rendering is not a big concern for fallback UI because it can be considered edge case.

Comment: Nice! could you also explain to me the 3rd point a just added to question?

Comment: Sure. Updated the answer.

Comment: One piece of the info in OP is incorrect (as is the info in Reddit thread it links to). `getDerivedStateFromError` is NOT called during server-side-rendering. I have tested this in both React 16.4 and 16.7. React docs https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html state "Error boundaries do not catch errors for... Server side rendering"

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ssr-error-boundary is a workaround which makes error boundaries work on the server, which can be used until the new React async renderer appears later this year.

Comment: Does that mean if I want to display a toast message over the existing UI, say "no network connection", I could just use `componentDidCatch`?

Comment: @Jonathan Probably yes, this depends on your case. Is an error caused by connection problem really caught by componentDidCatch? If it's not then it's likely shouldn't be used.

Comment: Can someone explain why `getDerivedStateFromError` is static? How is it able to return a new state if state isn't static? Non-static fields can not be accessed by static methods, can they?

Comment: @steak_Overcooked That the method is static suggests that it doesn't need to access an instance and this would be considered undesirable. It's lifecycle hook that is triggered by the framework, it doesn't matter for it if it's static or not. It acts as a pure function, receives an error as input and returns partial state as output. The state isn't entirely new. It's merged with `state`.

Answer (score 19):

Both of these methods are called when there is an error during rendering, in a lifecycle method, or in the constructor of any child component. They can be used while implementing Error boundaries

According to the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromerror)

`getDerivedStateFromError` lifecycle is invoked after an error has been thrown by a descendant component. It receives the error that was thrown as a parameter and should return a value to update state.

---

> are they both catching the same type of errors? or each lifecycle will
>   catch the different error?

Both of these lifecycle methods will catch the same errors, but the arguments to both of these components are different.

While `getDerivedStateFromError` receives just the error as the arguments, componentDidCatch also receives the second parameter which is `info, i.e  An object with a componentStack key containing information about which component threw the error.`

`getDerivedStateFromError()` is called during the “render” phase, so side-effects are not permitted. For those use cases, use `componentDidCatch()` instead. While `componentDidCatch` can also be used to setState but this will be deprecated in future releases

`componentDidCatch` should be used for sideEffects like logging errors

---

Also `@Brian Vaughn` has elaborated more on their usage on the link that you provide

> **`getDerivedStateFromError`  works with server-side rendering.**
>   componentDidCatch is a commit phase lifecycle, but there is no commit
>   phase on the server. getDerivedStateFromError is a render phase
>   lifecycle, and so it can be used to enable error handling on the
>   server.
>
> **Render phase recovery is safer.** The story for error recovery via
>   `componentDidCatch` is a little janky, since it relies on an
>   intermediate commit of "null" for everything below the component that
>   errored. This might result in subsequent errors inside of any
>   components higher up in the tree that implement componentDidMount or
>   componentDidUpdate and just assume that their refs will be non-null
>   (because they always are in the non-error case).
>
> **`getDerivedStateFromError` doesn't force sync rendering**. Because state-updates from commit
>   phase lifecycles are always synchronous, and because componentDidCatch
>   is called during the commit phase– using componentDidCatch for error
>   recovery is not optimal because it forces the fallback UI to always
>   render synchronously. (This is admittedly not a huge concern, since
>   error recovery should be an edge case.)
>
> In the event of an error, your error boundary's
>   `getDerivedStateFromError()` method will first be called (to update
>   state), then the render() method (to actually render the fallback UI),
>   and then `componentDidCatch` (once the fallback UI has been committed to
>   the DOM).
>
> If your error boundary defines other lifecycle methods (e.g.
>   componentWillUpdate, componentDidUpdate) they will also get called,
>   just like they would on any other render.

---

> "using componentDidCatch for error recovery is not optimal because it
>   forces the fallback UI to always render synchronously" what's wrong
>   with that?

what it means is that , componentDidCatch is called after the render method which renders fallback UI and that might lead to more issues while `getDerivedStateFromError` updates state before the render phase so that the correct fallback UI is rendered and no more errors are caused to the rendered components. Also the new releases aim at async rendering which might have issues with the current approach

Comment: "using componentDidCatch for error recovery is not optimal because it forces the fallback UI to always render synchronously". I don't fully understand what it means that it will "render synchronously"? I mean, what's wrong with that?

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk, what it means is that , componentDidCatch is called after the render method which renders fallback UI and that might lead to more issues while getDerivedStateFromError updates state before the render phase so that the correct fallback UI is rendered and no more errors are caused to the rendered components. Also the new releases aim at async rendering which might have issues with the current approach

Answer (score 6):

Actually, Both of them have the same goal but in a different phase, definitely, for writing `ErrorBoundary` component I use the `getDerivedStateFromError` method because I obey the [ReactJs Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#introducing-error-boundaries). the doc has this sentence:

> Use static `getDerivedStateFromError()` to render a fallback UI after an error has been thrown. Use `componentDidCatch()` to log error information.

Surely, it has some reasons so for rendering fallback UI I always use `getDerivedStateFromError` and for catching information and do something I use `componentDidCatch`.

Comment: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/wqvxGa So is this example kinda wrong, as it sets state in `componentDidCatch` instead of setting it in `getDerivedStateFromError `? Thank you