# ErrorBoundary not being triggered by error in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I implemented an ErrorBoundary like this:

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            hasError: false
        };
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
        // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
        alert("alert1");
        return { hasError: true };
    }

    componentDidCatch(error, info) {
        // Display fallback UI
        alert("alert2");
        this.setState({ hasError: true });
    }

    render(){
        const { t } = this.props;
        if(this.state.hasError) {
            return(
                <div>
                    <Navbar t={t} />

                    <div id="error-container">
                        <h1 id="error-title">Error title</h1>           
                        <p id="error-status">Error 404</p>      
                        <p id="error-message">Error message</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="link1-container">
                        <a href="%" id="error-link1">Volver</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="link2-container">
                    <a href="%" id="error-link1">Volver2</a>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            );
        } 
        return this.props.children;
    }

}

export default withTranslation()(ErrorBoundary);
```

My idea is to use this as a global erro handler so in my App.js I made the following:

```
function App() {
  return (

    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Suspense fallback={(<div>Loading</div>)}>
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <Route path="/publication" component={Details} />
        </ErrorBoundary>
        </Suspense>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

And then I want to try this to catch an error on my Details.js page. I do get an error 'Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'publicationID' of undefined' at line 51 (inside the componentDidMount) and I want to show my ErrorBoundary instead of that.

```
class Details extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            publicationID: null,
            province: null,
            city: null,
            neighborhood: null,
            address: null,
            bedrooms: null,
            bathrooms: null,
            floorSize: null,
            parking: null,
            price: null,
            title: null,
            description: null,
            image: null,
            maxImages: null,
            ownerEmail: null,
            phoneNumber: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const queryString = require('query-string');
        const query = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)
        const component = this

            axiosRequest.getPublication(query.publicationID).then(function (pub){
                axiosRequest.getImage(query.publicationID,0,pub).then(function (img){
                    component.setState({
                        publicationID: pub.publicationID, //this is line 51
                        province: pub.provinceID,
                        city: pub.cityID,
                        neighborhood: pub.neighborhoodID,
                        address: pub.address,
                        bedrooms: pub.bedrooms,
                        bathrooms: pub.bathrooms,
                        floorSize: pub.dimention,
                        parking: pub.parking,
                        price: pub.price,
                        title: pub.title,
                        description: pub.description,
                        image: img,
                        maxImages: pub.images,
                        phoneNumber: pub.phoneNumber,
                        ownerEmail: pub.userEmail
                    })
                })
            })

    }

    render(){
    ...
```

Comment: Can you tell me Which line is 51?

Comment: @jdn just updated my question

Comment: TL;DR [React's error boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) doesn't catch error in async code, like your promise callbacks.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I don't really see how the answers to that question are supposed to help me.

Comment: See the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52963052/1218980), it goes into details on what kind of errors are caught.

Comment: To solve the problem, you could catch the error manually, then, set the state with an error flag, then throw in one of the lifecycle method, like `render`, if the flag is truthy.