# How is state changed without this.setState method here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

This is my component

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
     }

static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
// Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
return { hasError: true };

  }
```

I am not getting how return statement is changing the state if we can't change state without `this.setState()` method?

Comment: The class component is required here, i think functional component with hooks more understandble. By the way, you have to understand how object works in javascript.

Comment: please can you explain me in detail how state is changed here?

Comment: In the first place you declare state with hasError key, later in getDerivedState .. method you simply update value inside state by key. might be this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52962851/whats-the-difference-between-getderivedstatefromerror-and-componentdidcatch will help you to become more familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's hard to tell how it can change state without calling `this.setState()`. The official docs only tells us to return an object in `getDerivedStateFromError()` method. Therefore, you could think this way: React using `getDerivedStateFromError()` returned value as `this.setState()` params so that new state being updated.

You can check offical document for the api, and this repo for more:
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/a9abd27e4f5aa1e68bd6035be901299327279ee2/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactUpdateQueue.js#L418-L423